# Can I use the Javascript 1.7+ iterators and generators inside a Firefox web worker?

Tags: javascript, firefox, web-worker

Or how do I tell Firefox to parse a web worker extension with mimetype `application/javascript;version=1.7`?

Firebug 1.7a9 in Firefox 4 Beta 9 gives:

```
missing ; before statement
[Break On This Error] yield k;
```

which is what it says when it doesn't recognize the generator yield keyword in a regular script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serve the file with that HTTP header. What server are you running?

Comment: I just tried node.js and renamed my file with a .js7 extension, which mapped to the application/javascript;version=1.7 mimetype. So, it served with that mimetype in that Content-Type header according to Firebug, but throws the same error from the worker instead of the browser (so I guess it parsed properly but still executes with the wrong type if Mozilla implemented the standards version of the web-worker interface, which doesn't account for non-standard ECMAscript extensions). Anyway, curiosity satisfied.

Comment: @user: Cool! Sorry I couldn't be more specific with my answer, as I didn't know what server you're running.